# Benchmark extra macro

Tags: benchmarking, weight, balances

What does the #[extra] macro do in benchmarks?

I was looking at how benchmarks are being implemented on the Balances pallet. I notice the following [benchmarks](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/blob/master/frame/balances/src/benchmarking.rs#L59):

```
benchmarks_instance_pallet {
  transfer {}

  #[extra]
  transfer_best_case {}

 ...
}
```

When I searched the code for `T::WeightInfo::transfer_best_case()` I could not find where that was used in the balances code.

Can you please explain what the macro extra is doing?

Also, when looking at the benchmarks for transfer extrinsic I was expecting some seeded account data to calculate the worst-case scenario. Can you please explain the decision on not seeded accounts before hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's an undocumented tag allowing to skip some benchmarks unless `--extra` flag is given. It was introduced in [this PR](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/pull/6610). From the description:

> - A new `#[extra]` tag is introduced into the `benchmarks!` macro, allowing users to mark benchmarks as "extra" and have them excluded from the default running benchmarks.
> - Added `--extra` feature flag to benchmarking-cli to enable users to run the extra benchmarks

Comment: I see. I guess I do not understand why we would use this feature. Do you know?

Comment: As far as I understand, it is meant to write benchmarks that are just for the developer's information, but their results are not supposed to be included in the pallet's `WeightInfo`.